# Azure Function app keys gets changed frequently

Tags: node.js, .net, azure, azure-functions, azure-http-trigger

I have created a Azure HTTP Trigger function app, and i will consuming that as a rest api in my .Net application, but problem i am facing is, few days once i see keys are getting changed and my .Net app is failing to consume that function app. What is the reason for this key change? what is the solution for this?

[image]

Comment: So you're saying the function key that's passed to your function to authenticate the calling app is changing?  On it's own?

Comment: Do you see anything logged in the activity log of the function app?

Comment: yes its changing on its own, in activity log i see, Restart Web App & List Web Apps Functions Host Keys thats it..

Answer (score 0):

**If the auto-generated keys for the Azure Function app change once in a few days automatically, then I would suggest you create the new function key manually and use it in the Azure Function URL**.

**That does not change until you replace the existing value manually of that key**

[image]

**and you can also auto-generate the new key for the key you created if you want a random generated value.**

[image]